# can't initialize inherited public member in derived class using constructor initializer list but y constructor is working

Tags: c++

why it’s not working though A::int i is visible in class B if so then why line1 is perfectly executing?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
int i;
};

class B : public A{
public:
//B(int j){i=j;} //line 1

    B(int j):i(j)
    {

    }
};

int main(){
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get compile errors trying to build

Comment: The error message tells you why. Read it. [Problem accessing base member in derived constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947583/problem-accessing-base-member-in-derived-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
public:
int i;
};

class B : public A{
public:
//B(int j){i=j;} //line 1

B(int j):i(j)   // line 2
{}
};
```

Default initializer list can only be used to initialize the members of the current class. In this case (line 2), you're initializing a base class member.

Look at the following snippet:

```
int a;
a = 2;
int b = 3;
```

`a` is declared in a statement and is assigned a value in another. Whereas, b is assigned a value **while** it is declared.

This is exactly how default initializers work.

```
class C
{
    int c;
    public:
        C() { c = 5; }
};

class D
{
    int d;
    public:
        D() : d(5) { }
};
```

`c` is assigned a value after symbol declaration whereas `d` gets a value **at the time of it's definition`**.

Answer (score 0):

Although `i` is visible from `B` it is not one of its data members and so it is not available in the initializer-list for `B`. What you can do is give `A` a constructor and call `A`'s constructor in `B`'s initializer-list:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    int i;

    A(int i): i(i) {}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
//B(int j){i=j;} //line 1

    B(int i): A(i) {} // call A's constructor
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```